# Interactuar con controles creados de manera dinamica

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Hola a todos estoy diseñandoun tablero dejuego con el control image, y esto controles los genero de manera dinamica, este es el codigo que utilizo:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 Dim i, j, top, left, z As Integer
 top = 0
 left = 0
 z = 1
 For i = 1 To 5
    For j = 1 To 8
        Set Imagen = userform1.Controls.Add("Forms.Image.1")
        With Imagen
            '.Name = "img" & j
            .AutoSize = True
            .Picture = LoadPicture("C:\Users\Sebastián Valencia\Desktop\Nueva carpeta (2)\" & z & ".jpg")
            .PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeStretch
            .top = top
            .left = left
            left = left + 108
            z = z + 1
        End With
    Next
    left = 0
    top = top + 115
    j = 1
Next
```

End Sub

Este codigo me crea 40 image, pero lo que quiero ahora es saber a cual de ellos lo presione para asignarle una imagen diferente,no he logrado encontrar la solucion al problema.

Gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar

Comment: bueno y que has intentando para llevar ese control de conteo de click por imagenes?????? creo que a tu objetivo le falta codigo ... tiene que en teoria... caturar el evento de click en la imagen y llevarlo a un contado por imagen ... eso lo puedes hacer con un arreglo ... pero todo eso tienes que programarlo, son solo conceptos ...

Comment: Hola, no se como hacerlo, si me ayudas

Comment: ok primero tienes que buscar en google como hacerlo... hay muchos tutoriales

Comment: Me imagino que las imágenes tendrán eventos asociados. Juega con el evento correspondiente (no sé si click o activate) para que envíe la información de dónde se ha hecho clic. [Aquí](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.image) puedes ver los eventos asociados en la parte izquierda